# How to output debug log in `build.rs`?

Tags: rust

I want to output some debug info in the [wasm_builder](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/utils/wasm-builder/Cargo.toml), What is the right way to do this? We cannot use normally runtime `log::debug!(...)` approach here, as the `build.rs` is compiled with the node build process. I have tried to use `println!(...)` directly, seems not work.

Comment: I suggest to ask this question in Rust stackoverflow rather than Substrate stackexchange

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short, you can not print from a `build.rs` file by default. It only prints the output when the `build.rs` returns an error. So, you could print what you are interested in and then panic or exit the process. Then you will see your output.

However, you can also print warnings from a `build.rs` file that are always printed.

```
println!("cargo:warning=MESSAGE");
```

You can find more information [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargo-warning).